# github pull request includes a commit updating my repository with upstream but I don't want this

Tags: git, github

What am I doing wrong?

I have a cloned repository.

1. I have made some changes in master.
2. I have also done a `git pull upstream/master` to keep my master in line.

I want to send my changes upstream via a github pull request.
So I push my local changes back to my github clone.
However, the pull request includes `2` as well as `1`.

I don't want to send back to upstream the commit relating to `2`
I am a git newbie obviously.

Comment: There is a command `git rebase` to replay changes in another place.  see `man git-rebase` for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `git pull upstream/master` you should've done `git pull --rebase upstream/master`. This would've downloaded the upstream changes and applied yours on top of those as if they were made later (but keeping the git history linear which is what we want).

Comment: thanks. I will do this in future. After rebasing, my open github pull request automatically changed to one commit showing only my changes.